# How to get Table data values as variables using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

i have a page on the browser that displays some items in a table format. now i want to select particular items (rows) and then get the data (columns values) of those selected rows as variables in a Javascript function so i can use them as parameters in a query string on an ASP page.

```
function selectedRows() 
{
   var selectedItems = Hesto.UI.GetSelectedItems('#ScannedLabelTable');
   $.each(selectedItems, function (i, item) {
   $.ajax({
   url: PRINT_LABELS_QUERY_PAGE
         , data:  // this is where i need help on..
     , dataType: 'json'
     , success:alert("Labels Printed")
     , error: Hesto.Ajax.ErrorHandler
     });
});
FetchLabelDetails();
}
```

Comment: data: item.something - however I think you need to queue the ajax

Comment: or something like: `data: item.find('th').html()`

Answer (score 0):

From a table like this you can accept using `document.getElementById("").innerHTML` for taking from a particular cell

```
   <TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TD id='1'>abc</TD>
        <TD id='2'>efg</TD>
        <TD id='3'>hij</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD id='4'>lmno</TD>
        <TD id='5'>pqr</TD>
        <TD id='6'>stu</TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
```

you can use `document.getElementById("2").innerHTML` for getting `efg`

Comment: thanks bru it is working, but it only shows me the first data from the first row columns. i want it to show me the ones i will click on and select (selected rows)...

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me.......

```
$('#export').click(function() {
          //alert('clicked')
          var myRows = [];
            var $headers = $("th");
            var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
              $cells = $(this).find("td");
              myRows[index] = {};
              $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
                    myRows[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
              });    
            });
            var myObj = {};
            myObj.myrows = myRows;

            //alert(JSON.stringify(myObj));
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "your url",
                data: "objdata="+JSON.stringify(myObj),//passing data as json
                success: function(result){  
                    //alert('exported');
                }  
            });

          });
```

this will export all data's from table and save as json